# incrementing Number in Crystal Report

Tags: vb.net, formula, crystal-reports-2010

When I Click the button there should be a incrementing number in the report so i can track how many transaction did i print.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt = Me.grvData.DataSource

    Dim Cr As New VoucherExpense
    Cr.SetDataSource(dt)

    Dim r As New ReportForm
    r.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Cr
    r.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a count of your records then that is a summary field and very easy to do. Rather than try to tell you where to click in the UI you can look at a video https://youtu.be/-i2p5KPDl48?t=1m32s 
BUT if you want to have a number for each record given by crystal you can also use rownum which is one of the special fields of crystal (other special fields are page number or print date etc). You can make a formula and just put rownum).

Comment: Ive tried to use record number in my crystal report . when i click the button print it display 1 but when i clicked it again it is still 1 . how can i make it 2 and onwards depend on how many time i click the button ?

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Reports (and any other reports) are used to display/print data. You can format it or do calculations on the data given e.g. a count of the records in that report or a sum to show totals BUT once the report is closed it will not "remember" anything. So to get the number of times a transaction was printed you have to increment and save it in your database. So the number of times it was printed is one database field on that row and your button should to an update/increment of that database value right before you show the report. If you want to store the actual "Print" to the printer and not just preview of the report on the screen then you can put your database increment logic on the event handler of the print button of the crystal reports viewer